# Reducing the order of differential equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, reduction-of-order-ode

How the following 4th order linear differential equation can be reduced to two 2nd order differential equations, if possible. $a$ and $b$ are constants.

$$X^2  Y^{(4)}(X) + 2  (a+2)  X  Y^{(3)}(X) + (a+2) (a+1)  Y''(X) - b^4  Y(X) = 0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Where is that problem coming from? More context is needed here. Also, you want an exact reduction or an approximate one?

Comment: I am interested in exact reduction